# How can I check that an entry in one column of a tables appears at least once in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of words that looks like this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordForm] (
    [Word1]  VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [Word2]  VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
}
```

Here's what the data looks like?

```
Word1       Word2
-----       -----
abandon     abandon
abandon     abandonment
adapt       adapt
adapt       adaptable
adapt       adaptation
adapt       adapter
adversely   adverse
adversely   adversely
adversely   adversity
```

How can I check that every word which appears in column Word1 is present in Word2 at least once and also if there are words that appears in Word1 but not Word2 I need to know what the words are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more performant solution on large datasets try this:

```
SELECT w.Word1 as [Word 1 Not in Word 2]
FROM   WordForm w
EXCEPT
SELECT w.Word2
FROM   WordForm w
;

SELECT w.Word2 as [Word 2 Not in Word 1]
FROM   WordForm w
EXCEPT
SELECT w.Word1
FROM   WordForm w
;
```

Comment: @Alan, can you explain which of the above 2 queries answers this `every word which appears in column Word1 is present in Word2`? Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT w.Word1 as [Word 1 Not in Word 2]
FROM   WordForm w
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
            SELECT *
            FROM   WordForm x
            WHERE  x.Word2 = w.Word1
       )

SELECT w.Word2 as [Word 2 Not in Word 1]
FROM   WordForm w
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
            SELECT *
            FROM   WordForm x
            WHERE  x.Word1 = w.Word2
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 native operators for this, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`:

```
select word1 from wordform
intersect
select word2 from wordform

select word1 from wordform
except
select word2 from wordform
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx